# On real roots of a polynomial equation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, polynomials

Let $f(x)=x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$ such that if $f(r)=0$ , then $ f ' (r) \ne 0$ i.e. $f$ has no double-root in $\mathbb C$ i.e. $f$ has three distinct roots with at least one real root. Let $g(x) = 2 f''(x) f(x) - (f'(x))^2$.

Then how to show that $g$ has exactly two real roots ? If $r< s$ are the two real roots of $g(x)$, then how to show that $f(r) <0$ and $f(s) >0$ ?

Since $g'(x)=12 f(x)$, so $g$ has degree $4$ and since $f$ has no double root , so all the 4 roots of $g$ are also distinct. I am unable to say anything else. Please help.

Comment: Given the conditions on the equation (coefficients all real and no double root) then the equation has either one or three real roots.  It cannot have exactly two real roots, since the coefficients could not all be real when one root is not real.

Comment: @herbsteinberg The “exactly two real roots” refers to $g$, which has degree $4$.

Answer (score 4):

As $g'(x)=12f(x)$, all local extrema of $g$ are at roots $r$ of $f$, $f(r)=0$. As these local extrema of $g$ the value $g(r)=-f'(r)^2<0$ is negative, even if $f$ has 3 real roots, the local maximum still has a negative value.  As the leading term of $g$ is $3x^4$, for large $|x|$ the value of $g$ becomes positive. Thus there are roots of $g$ left and right of the root set of $f$. As $g$ is monotonous on those segments, there is exactly one root of $g$ left of the leftmost root of $f$ and one right of the rightmost one.

In other words, let $a=\min\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)=0\}$ and $b=\max\{x\in\Bbb R:f(x)=0\}$. Then $g$ is negative on $[a,b]$ and monotonous falling resp. increasing on $(-\infty,a]$ and $[b,\infty)$ with a sign change and thus exactly one root in each of the intervals.

---

Or another way using more directly the degree of $g$: if $g$ had $4$ real roots $s_1\le s_2\le s_3\le s_4$, then $g(x)=3(x-s_1)(x-s_2)(x-s_3)(x-s_4)$ would take non-negative values in the interval $[s_2,s_3]$, thus also at the local maximum $r$ there, which is impossible by the first observation, $g(r)=-f'(t)^2$ and $f'(r)\ne0$ as $r$ is also one root of $f$, and a simple one at that.

Comment: Which segments do you mean when you say "$g$ is monotonous on those segments" ?

Comment: Added 2 sentences on that.

Comment: This shows that $g$ has atmost 2 real roots. But why does it have atleast 1 real root ?

Comment: @misao : Because the leading coefficient is positive. And $g$ has negative values.

Comment: Thanks ...  and why if $a<b$ are roots of $g$, then $f(a) <0$ and $f(b) >0$ ?

Comment: Because the leading term of $f$ is $x^3$ and the roots of $g$ are outside the interval that contains the roots of $f$.

Comment: Could you please elaborate ? I can only see that $g$ and $f$ has no common root...

Comment: As per the first approach, if $a_f, b_f$ are the smallest and largest real roots of $f$, and $a_g,b_g$ those of $g$, then $a_g<a_f$ and $b_f<b_g$. As $f$ is negative on $(-\infty,a_f)$ and positive on $(b_f,\infty)$, the claim follows.

Answer (score 0):

*Updated 20.02*

Using expressions for $f(x)$ and $g(x),$ [one can get](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3(h+%2B+2d)%5E2+%2B+12(c+-+a(d+%2B+a*a%2F27))+(x%2Ba%2F3)+-+36d%5E2,+where+h+%3D+(x%2Ba%2F3)%5E2%2B+d,+d+%3D+b%2F3+-+a%5E2%2F9):
$$f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2ax +b = 3\left(\left(x + \frac a3\right)^2 + d\right),\tag1$$
$$g(x) = 3x^4 + 4ax^3 + 6bx^2 + 12cx + 4ac - b^2,$$
$$g(x) = 3\left(\left(x + \frac a3\right)^2 + d\right)^2 - 36d^2 + 12k\left(x + \frac a3\right),\tag2$$
$$f(x) = \frac1{12}g'(x) = \left(x + \frac a3\right)\left(\left(x + \frac a3\right)^2 + d\right) + k,\tag3$$
where
$$d = \frac b3 - \frac {a^2}9,\quad k = c - ad - \frac{a^3}{27}.$$

**Case** $\underline {d=0}.$

Taking in account $(1)$ and $(3),$ the issue condition
$$f(x) = 0 \rightarrow f'(x) \not= 0\tag4$$
means that $k \not= 0.$
So
$$g(x) = 3\left(x + \frac a3\right)\left(\left(x + \frac a3\right)^3 + 4k\right)$$
has exactly 2 real roots.

**Case** $\underline {d \not= 0}.$

Let $$y = x + \dfrac a3,$$
$$G(y) = g(y - \frac a3) = (3y^2 + d)^2 -36d^2 + 12 ky.$$
Easy to see that:
$$G(0) = -27d^2 < 0,$$
$$G\left(\pm\infty\right) = +\infty.$$
So continuous function $G(x)$ has at least 2 real roots.

On the other hand, $$G''(y) = 12y(3y^2 + d).$$
So G(y) can't have more than one zero, one positive and one negative extremums. That means that it can't have more than two positive and two negative roots.

At the same time, according to Viete's theorem, function $G(y)$ has negative production of roots, so both of additional roots must have the same sign.

This contradiction means that both $G(x)$ and $g(x)$ have exactly 2 real roots in this case too.

We have shown that $g(x)$ **has exactly 2 real roots**.

Comment: `f′(x) is the set of two constant lines` Didn't follow the calculations, but this conclusion looks wrong. For one thing, what does it even mean that "$\,f'(x)\,$ `is the set of two constant lines`"? Then, $\,f'(x)\,$ is a second degree polynomial, which is certainly not constant on any interval.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your edit. Other than removing the previously quoted line, result $\,(5)\,$ still appears to imply that $\,f'(x)\,$ can only take one of two values. That's obviously not the case, since $\,f'\,$ is a non-degenerate quadratic. Try any simple example, like $\,a=b=c=1\,$.

Comment: I don't see any substantial change. $\,(5)\,$ *still* appears to imply that $\,f'(x)\,$ can only take a couple of fixed values, which is plain wrong. Try your argument on $\,f(x)=x^3+x^2+x+1\,$, and it should become obvious where it fails.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov I think you misread the definition of $g$. $g$ is $2ff''-(f')^2$ (notice the $2$ coefficient), not $ff''-(f'^2)$

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Old version was not correct and now it have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in LutzL's partial answer, $g$ must have at least two distinct real roots $\alpha,\beta$. Suppose by contradiction that $\frac{g(x)}{(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}$ has a real root, which will then be a root of $g$ also. Then, since $g$ has degree $4$, all the roots of $g$ are real. Denote them by $g_1,g_2,g_3,g_4$. From $g(x)=3x^4 + 4ax^3 + 6bx^2 + 12cx + 4ac - b^2=3(x-g_1)(x-g_2)(x-g_3)(x-g_4)$, we deduce

$$
\begin{array}{lcl}
a &=& -\frac{3}{4}\big(g_1+g_2+g_3+g_4\big), \\
b &=& \frac{1}{2}\big(g_1g_2+g_1g_3+g_2g_3+g_1g_4+g_2g_4+g_3g_4\big), \\
c &=& -\frac{1}{4}\big(g_1g_2g_3+g_1g_2g_4+g_1g_3g_4+g_2g_3g_4\big) \\ 
\end{array} \tag{1}
$$

and the last coefficient of $g$ being $4ac-b^2=3g_1g_2g_3g_4$, we see that $G=0$ where

$$
G=\sum_{i,j} g_i^2g_j^2 +6g_1g_2g_3g_4 - \sum_{i,j,k} g_ig_jg_k^2 \tag{2}
$$

Now, if we put $k_1=g_1^2+g_2^2+g_3^2-g_1g_2-g_1g_3-g_2g_3=
\frac{1}{2}.((g_1-g_2)^2+(g_1-g_3)^2+(g_2-g_3)^2)$, $k_2=\sum_{i,j}g_i^2g_j-6g_1g_2g_3$
and $k_3=((g_1-g_2)(g_1-g_3)(g_2-g_3))$, we have the identity

$$
16k_1G=(2k_1g_4+k_2)^2+3k_3^2 \tag{3}
$$

It follows that $2k_1g_4+k_2=0$ and $k_3=0$. So at least two among $g_1,g_2,g_3$ are equal ; assume without loss that $g_2=g_1$. Then, $2k_1g_4+k_2=0$ becomes $2(g_3-g_1)^2(g_4-g_1)=0$, which forces $g_1$ to be a triple root for $g$, hence a double root for $f$, which is excluded by the hypotheses.